# Mapping Page of MyObject to Page of MyObjectDTO

Tags: java, apache-camel, dozer

I use camel-dozer for mapping MyObject to MyObjectDTO in my project. Spring repository return `Page<MyObject>`. I need to mapping `Page<MyObject>` to `Page<MyObjectDTO>`. Is exist nice way for this mapping without iteration Page.content and convert for each item?

I mapping single object this way:

dozerBeanMapping.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping http://dozermapper.github.io/schema/bean-mapping.xsd">

    <mapping>
        <class-a>ru.test.MyObject</class-a>
        <class-b>ru.test.MyObjectDTO</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>myField</a>
            <b>testField</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

RestRoute.java

```java
  rest("/search").description("")
                .get("/{id}")
                .consumes("application/json").to("direct:getMyObjectByID")

 from("direct:getMyObjectByID")
                .routeId("direct:getMyObjectByID")
                .bean("myObjectRepository", "getMyObjectById(${header.id})")
                .to("dozer:transformMyObjectDTO?mappingFile=dozerBeanMapping.xml&targetModel=ru.test.MyObjectDTO")
```

Answer (score 0):

My temporary horrible solution: return immediately list of DTO from Spring Data repository.

```java
@Repository("myObjectRepository")
public interface MyObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Integer> {

 @Query(value = "SELECT new ru.test.MyObjectDTO(l.id, l.otherfields)" +
            " from MyObject l where l.otherObject=:otherObject")
    Page<MyObjectDTO> getAllByOtherObject(@Param("otherObject") OtherObject otherObject, Pageable pageable);
}
```